# Python: multiprocessing append to list outside function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to write a function that will append to a list outside of itself in python. Test that with a for loop no problem there. However, when I try to get it to run with multiprocessing it no longer works.
I've created a much simpler code that demonstrates the problem for troubleshooting:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

items = []
def myFunc(a,b):
    data = (a,b)
    items.append(data)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(2) as p:
        p.starmap(myFunc,[(0,1),(2,3)])

    print(items)
```

should come back with

```
[(0,1),(2,3)]
```

As it does with the for loop, instead the list is empty,
Any pointers?

Comment: Try this fast change, items = multiprocessing.Manager().list()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just return the data once it has been manipulated and then add it to the items list.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
    
items = []
def myFunc(a,b):
    data = (a,b)

    # manipulate data...

    return data
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(2) as p:
        items += p.starmap(myFunc,[(0,1),(2,3)])
    
    print(items)
```

output:

```py
[(0, 1), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: I will upvote this answer because for this simple case your solution will surely work. But what if `myFunc` was doing something more complicated, perhaps changing existing elements of the the `items` list? Then returning values as opposed to modifying the actual list would not be a natural approach and you would have to solve the problem of how to do that, which was really inherent in the OP's question.

Comment: @Booboo, thanks. I totally agree that your answer is much better in a general case. My approach was merely a result of the simplicity of OP:s example code... Your answer has my upvote too xP

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use a `list` obtained by a `SyncManager` instance obtained by calling `multiprocessing.Manager()` and passing this as an argument to `myfunc`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import functools

def myFunc(items, a, b):
    data = (a,b)
    items.append(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    items = manager.list()
    with Pool(2) as p:
        p.starmap(functools.partial(myFunc, items),[(0,1),(2,3)])

    print(items)
```

Prints:

```
[(2, 3), (0, 1)]
```

The other way, which is closer to what you have, is to initialize each process in the pool with this special sharable inter-process `list` and not have to pass it as an argument to your workers:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

def init_processes(l):
    global items

    items = l


def myFunc(a, b):
    data = (a,b)
    items.append(data)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    items = manager.list()
    with Pool(2, initializer=init_processes, initargs=(items,)) as p:
        p.starmap(myFunc, [(0,1),(2,3)])

    print(items)
```

Prints:

```
[(0, 1), (2, 3)]
```

**So it becomes a question of passing the list once per job submission (i.e. once for each argument in the call to `starmap`) versus once for each process in your pool.** In your case it is pretty much the same thing in terms of cost I would think, but generally the second approach would be better.

You will note that the order in which the tuples are added is non-deterministic according to which call finishes first. The return values from the calls, however, would be in strict order of the calls:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import functools

def myFunc(items, a, b):
    data = (a,b)
    items.append(data)
    return data # let's also return the tuple


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    items = manager.list()
    with Pool(2) as p:
        results = list(p.starmap(functools.partial(myFunc, items),[(0,1),(2,3)]))

    print(items)
    print(results)
```

Prints:

```
[(2, 3), (0, 1)]
[(0, 1), (2, 3)]
```

I had to run the above several times to get the resulting `items` array to be `[(2, 3), (0, 1)]` rather than `[(0, 1), (2, 3)]`, but you can still see that the return values from the call to `myFunc` correspond to the order in which the "jobs" were submitted.

Comment: Wow man this is the best answer I saw in this question. I was going to learn multi-threading too, and I assume that this answer is surely going to help me, I don't know if I could save this answer for later ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing implies the code is run in another process. That is even in another Python runtime.

The calling machinery serialises your list, and de-serialize it in the other process in a seamless way, but it is a 200% percent independent and separate object on the other side (100% for not being the same list, + 100% for being in another process :-) )

What the language offers closer to a list is the [`multiprocessing.Queue` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) - that is a sequence-like object that operates the inter-process comunication part in a transparent way

While you could use concurrent.futures to easily get return values back from off-process worker functions and that could lead to an easier to understand code base, that would be further from a design you've thought using "lists". (Although I'd recommend it)